# angular UI Bootstrap: ng-click on progress bar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap UI *progress bar* component to show the elapsed time of an audio player.

I am wondering if there is a way to bind the progress bar to user actions like ng-click and returning the new value where the click was "clicked". This should help me implement a seek function for the audio player.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented it this way:

template:

```
<div ng-click="tracksCtrl.handleProgressBarClick($event)">
  <progressbar value="tracksCtrl.playingProgress" type="danger"></progressbar>
</div>
```

part of controller code:

```
handleProgressBarClick: function(e) {
  var fullProgressBarWidth = $(e.currentTarget).width();
  var requestedPosition = e.offsetX / fullProgressBarWidth * 100;
  setPlayerPercent(requestedPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think bootstrap UI progress bar provides feature you want. But you can implement seek function by using `offsetX` or `offsetY` of `MouseEvent`.